# Load Specific Part of NSArray in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am using an NSArray to load objects into my UICollectionView. The UICollectionView has a UIPageViewController associated with it where I am grabbing the index for each page. Depending on what page you are on, I want to load different objects.

I try to do that using the following:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
if (self.index == 0) {
    dictionary = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (self.index == 1) {
    dictionary = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:12 + indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.imageArray);
} else if (self.index == 2) {
    dictionary = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:24 + indexPath.row];
}
```

Where `self.index` is the page you are on.

However, I keep getting the following crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 48 beyond bounds [0 .. 47]'
```

However, my array does have 48 objects. There are 12 objects loaded on each page.

Does it have anything to do with me setting the dictionary each time? Only thing I could think of....

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Indexing starts at 0. The 48 objects are indexed 0 through 47. Attempts to access index 48 is out of bounds.

Comment: How would you recommend I fix that @rmaddy? I don't think I ever access 48?

Comment: Fix whatever is causing the problem so it knows the indexes are 0-47 and not 1-48.

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with loading 12 objects per page and there are 4 pages? @rmaddy

Comment: Debug your code and see where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using those ugly `if`s and twisted logic, try to structure your model better. One way of doing this would be to have an array of arrays: each page an array of images. You'd know the pages count from the model and accessing the right image would be as simple as `self.images[self.index][indexpath.row]` You could also use an `UIcollectionview` with each page a section.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Sorry not following totally.